# Docker needs to be installed each time I restart the VM in Oracle VirtualBox

Tags: docker

I'm totally new to Docker and had few queries with the Docker installation.

I've Windows 7 64 bit OS and installed Oracle Virtualbox to run Ubuntu 16.04 ISO image.

I've installed Docker and it works fine.

The problem I face is, each time I shutdown the VM created in Virtualbox and start it again, I have to run the complete steps to setup Docker again. No settings are saved. Even the documents I save on Ubuntu desktop are gone. Can someone please help me understand as to why this happens?

One doubt I have is, each time when I start Ubuntu, I opt to run from the CD. Could this be the reason?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/n1jhv.jpg)

Comment: Yes that is why.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you should instead go through the installation. Then you can even disconnect the optical drive to use less resources and avoid confusion in the future.

Comment: To clarify, you need to run through the Ubuntu installation to hard drive. When you boot the ISO, there should be a second option in the boot menu to "Install Ubuntu". When you just run the "Try ubuntu" option, everything is running and installed to memory. Once you reboot the VM, the memory (and any work / installed programs) are lost.

Comment: Thanks Mano and Andy for the quick and detailed response.